# Access properties of Javascript variable

Tags: javascript

I want to access specific properties of a response object received from a GET Request to my server.

```
getRespondersInRange: function() {
    this.$http.get('v1/responders?'.concat("latitude=" + this.latitude + "&longitude=" + this.longitude)).then(function(response) {
        this.responders = response.data["data"];
        console.log(this.responders);
    }.bind(this));
},
```

The console.log returns this:

[image]

I want to access the field "userReference", but I can't find out how. I tried:

1. `console.log(this.responders["userReference"]`
2. `console.log(this.responders.userReference`

Comment: access the `0` index like `this.responders[0]["userReference"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns you an array, try to access property this way:

```
this.responders[0]["userReference"];
```